# How do I restrict remote AAD (Work/School) connected personal machines with Group Policy enforced from the AADDS VM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, group-policy

How do I restrict remote AAD (Work/School) connected personal machines with Group Policy enforced from the AADDS VM?

This client's company is fully remote and is looking for a cloud group policy solution.

Is there anyway to use AADDS to accomplish this task?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To manages machines/computers with group policy the machine should be joined with domain(on prem domain controller or azure adds) Once the machine is joined to domain you can apply group policies.

If you are looking to use azure ad ds managed instance . it gives the ability to join computers on a domain without any need to manage or deploy a Domain Controller. The users can sign-in by using their existing corporate credentials.
If you want to manage group policy with adds managed instance, you need to create an additional vm with sevrer OS and you need to install required server roles to preform additional operations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance

Or else you can use Azure AD registered devices, The goal of Azure AD registered devices is to provide your users with support for the bring your own device (BYOD) or mobile device scenarios.
You can find more information [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/) about device management in azure Azure AD.